# Using prototype PCBs as Arduino shield

Tags: shields, pcb-design, prototype

Is is possible to use prototype PCBs (PCB with grid of unconnected holes with copper around them, usually with pitch 2.54 mm) as Arduino shield, when they are fitted with appropriate pin headers?

I am asking this question because I am not sure whether the Arduino UNO pin headers (which are split) will fit to the headers on the prototype PCB where I will “leave out” one pin on the header.

(Yes, I ho not have a Arduino board to try it out now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the UNO style boards, no it's not possible. The digital headers have a 0.16 inch gap between them which offsets one set of headers 0.06" from the holes in the shield.

For this reason you can buy specific Arduino prototyping shields that have the headers in the right locations.

Comment: are you saying that the header pins are 0.16 inch apart?

Comment: @jsotola the *entire* header for pins 0-7 is not on the same 0.1 inch grid that the other three female headers collectively share together. Really, it's the distance between the center of digital pin 7 and center digital pin 8 being referred to. So without splitting hairs on about the distances between plastic housings and nearest distances and all that, it's the distance (by some definition) between two entire headers. That is, it's not referring to header's pin "pitch".

Comment: Yep, I thought that. Thank you.